# Network Meta-Analysis: Do all included studies influence all ESs?

Tags: effect-size, network-meta-analysis

I am reviewing a NMA of over 10 interventions with wait-list control (WLC) groups being chosen as the reference group by the authors. I have done some reading and watched some videos on NMA and was just trying to confirm if my understanding about them is accurate.

1. Will an ES from direct comparisons between two treatments (A and B) be influenced by available indirect comparisons in the network? For example, if the NMA includes studies that directly compared A to B, but also includes studies that compared A to WLC and B to WLC, will the ESs from the WLC comparisons potentially influence the direct A vs B ES or is it a case that when direct comparisons exist that the indirect ones are not incorporated in the NMA?
2. Related to the above question: Do all available studies included in a NMA influence all of the ESs? For example, one of the studies included in the NMA was a direct treatment comparison (A vs B) and has subsequently been found to have improperly delivered one of the two treatments (Treatment B). This improper delivery very likely made Treatment B 'fail' leading to a highly inflated ES for Treatment A and an understated ES for Treatment B; by 'highly inflated' I mean the ES is the highest of any study in the whole NMA. Is it likely that the inflated ES for A and understated ES for B will influence all of the other ESs (Treatments C, D, E, F, etc.), so in essence the inclusion of this study may bring into question the validity of all of the other ESs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this should go as a comment but I believe I've found an answer to the first question.

1. According to [Tianjing et al (2011)](https://bmcmedicine.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1741-7015-9-79): *"When both direct and indirect evidence are available, the two sources of information can be combined as a weighted average when appropriate."* So if direct and indirect comparisons exist ideally the authors should state if they have combined them. Frustratingly the NMA I'm reviewing doesn't state this either way so I'm not sure what they did.